# Как оптимизировать parallax эффект на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, css3, css-animation

Привет

Использую на сайте плагин [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) для парочки background'ов.

Плагин работает отлично, но если смотреть в инспекторе - он постоянно пересчитывает позицию bg по оси Y (translate3d), даже когда блок с параллаксом находится вне области просмотра.

Фотки на bg стоят хорошего разрешения и мне кажется постоянный перерасчет позиции background'да нагружает, тормозит сайт.

Как можно запускать parallax когда блок входит в область просмотра и останавливать translate3d когда блок с параллаксом выходит из области просмотра?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Большинство браузеров](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect) поддерживают метод элемента [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), который лучше всего подходит для определения - находится ли элемент в области просмотра или нет. Вот пример:

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {

    // если используется jQuery то можно передавать jQuery элемент
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight ||
            document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*или $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth ||
            document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*или $(window).width() */
    );
}
```

Эта функция вернёт `true` если элемент в области просмотра (viewport), иначе `false`. Ну а в остальном поможет ковыряние в потрохах плагина, ибо со временем он может измениться (*и такой ответ будет противоречить правилам платформы*).

#### Какие события стоит отлавливать

С jQuery

```
$(window).on('DOMContentLoaded load resize scroll', handler);
```

без-jQuery

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler, false);
    addEventListener('load', handler, false);
    addEventListener('scroll', handler, false);
    addEventListener('resize', handler, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent)  {
    attachEvent('onDOMContentLoaded', handler); // IE9+ :(
    attachEvent('onload', handler);
    attachEvent('onscroll', handler);
    attachEvent('onresize', handler);
}
```

Здесь `handler` - это функция обработчик.

#### Замечания

- jQuery может отлавливать увеличение/уменьшение (zoom) кроссбраузерно,включая мобильные, без jQuery нужно писать свои обработчики.
- Изменения в DOM не приведут к вызову обработчика и, если при этом изменилось положение элементов на странице, то нужно вызывать обработчик вручную.
- Стоит вызывать обработчик после загрузки стилей (после `DOMContentLoaded`) и изображений (`window.onload`), иначе по мере применения стилей и загрузки изображений объекты на странице будут перемещаться, но это никак нельзя будет отследить.
- Метод не реагирует на перекрытие элементом другим, с большим z-index например. Если элемент в области просмотра, неважно перекрыт он или нет, функция вернёт `true`
- То же самое касается и прокрутки внутри какого-нибудь элемента-контейнера. Объект может быть прокручен за область видимости, но при этом находиться в области видимости окна.

#### Примечание

Я не совсем уверен, что современные браузеры будут заниматься отрисовкой (render) чего либо, что находится за границей области просмотра (просто вычисление координат и размеров и всё). Но точно уверен,что отлавливание `scroll` и колдовство с этим связанное - даст дополнительную нагрузку.

[Находится ли элемент в области просмотра](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/1816872)(англ.)

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [viewport](/questions/tagged/viewport)

Comment: не знаю, решило ли это проблему автора, но пишите ещё )